# Magento 2 Enterprise install issue

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, composer, credentials

I am trying to install `Magento EE 2.0.2` on my local environment.
I download the version from my *magentocommerce* account.
When I run the `composer install` command it is all good except when it start to download `magento/module-worldpay` composant and I have the common error

> Installing magento/module-worldpay (100.0.3)
>       Downloading: Connecting...
>                                                                                                                                              [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   Invalid credentials for
>   'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-worldpay/magento-module-worldpay-100.0.3.0.zip',
>   aborting.

---

**Note that config work fine with an other Magento 2 CE version on the same environment.**

Before downvote my question there is the step I follow :
 - classic issue with `/Users/{user}/.composer/auth.json` file. I put my credentials in :

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<public key from magento commencer account linked to EE>",
            "password": "<private key from magento commencer account linked to EE>"
        }
    },
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "<Github token>"
    }
}
```

- I regenerate credentials from magentocommerce account
 - I run `composer clear-cache`

Do I miss something here ?
Is there any further action related to the EE version with the credentials ?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**
As noticed Maddy in answer, the downloaded ZIP include the `vendor/` directory with all the Magento Core / dependencies but in my case I work with GIT so I would like to be able to run `composer install` that I do not have to put the `vendor/` directory in my repository.

Comment: do you install via composer install/update or with some other script/method integrated in magento (not sure if there is one, but magento2 also has another composer env somewhere then the one in your home directory. It's used for example to install the sample data via magento console command)

Comment: Not sure to understand your question but this is the very first step of my Magento installation so I untar and run `composer install` at Magento root

Comment: ok, then your auth.json should be taken :o

Comment: Yes there is where I am stuck ;) All these steps work for a CE verison. The only problem is on an EE extension `wordlpay`.

Comment: hm ok, didn't try EE yet. maybe still a magento permission problem in the composer repository :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the zip from magento.com you shouldn't have to run `composer install` again. You should already have the vendor directory with all the required dependencies. Just go to [yourhost/setup and install Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html) or install via [CLI](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands.html). Do check for suggested [file permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html) and [users](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html) as in documentation.

---

If you are a contributing developer (making Pull Requests to the code base) you would use magento from git. If you are using shared hosting, use the downloaded zip. if you are a SI/extension dev use composer create-project The differences for each of these approaches and more are explained here: [devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html) If you are talking about saving an instance of your entire store, assuming you have other modules, it would be better to use the composer create-project and just checking in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` and other custom files.

Comment: I am working with GIT so I do not have the vendor direcotry yet. That is why I would like to install it through `composer install`. I did not the see the relation between my issue and your doc links ? It is a composer / magento repo credentials issue (I think...), for the moment I have no permissions to add.

Comment: OK after checking the dowloaded repo you're right there is the full vendor repository. In this case we have to put the entire vendor directory on GIT ? We lose composer utility right ?

Comment: If you are a contributing developer (making Pull Requests to the code base) you would use magento from git.  If you are using shared hosting, use the downloaded zip. if you are a SI/extension dev use composer create-project The differences for each of these approaches and more are explained here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html
If you are talking about saving an instance of your entire store, assuming you have other modules, it would be better to use the composer create-project and just checking in composer.json and composer.lock and other custom files.

Comment: I don't believe EE users can submit PRs so your option is either `composer create-project` or using a compressed archive. Neither of those require `composer install`.

You should use the partner portal to get support for EE.

Comment: OK great ! I was mistaken about the right way to install the EE version. I thought the `composer create-project` is only for CE versions. Thank you for the clarification !

Answer (score 1):

If your Magento account has been linked to your client's account, the permission to download the source code via composer is **not** automatic.

In my case, I had to open an issue at Magento support. They answered shortly after by saying they had granted the permissions to our account on the behalf of our client. I did this by reading on the Magento Forums where other users had the same issue.

Also, if you already have an entry for *repo.magento.com* in your auth.json file, you can stack them like this:

```
{
   "http-basic": {
       "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "personal-key",
            "password": "personal-secret-key"
       },
       "repo.magento.com": {
           "username": "client-key",
           "password": "client-secret-key"
       }
   }
}
```